# Accessing the contents of a Nameless folder

Tags: windows-7

I have a folder without a name and it contains data. I am unable to access it through explorer since it is hidden (Show hidden folder has no effect) and i could not use CD in cmd to open it as it has no name. Is there anyway i can open the directory and access its content. I am using windows 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is indeed possible to give a folder no name.

in CMD:

```
mkdir "\\?\C:\temp\ "
```

if you have something like this just write DIR and hit the tabulator. This steps through each folder. Do this until your nameless folder is displayed like

```
dir "C:\temp\ "
```

you can't directly CD into it, but you can display the contents.
After this you can copy each folder and file out of it.

```
copy "C:\temp\ \filename.txt" C:\temp
```

if this does not work try it with

```
copy "\\?\C:\temp\ \filename.txt" C:\temp
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, it's impossible to create a nameless folder. In your case, it seems the folder was named after some sort of whitespace or non-printable character. In that case, you can try going to the directory above it, and running

```
 dir /x
```

to list the directory contents to find its name (the `/x` flag will display its "short name" -- the filename that MS-DOS would see it as -- alongside its actual name). Then you can run `rename` to call it whatever you want -- just avoid those pesky invisible characters when you do ;]

Answer (score 0):

I ran a freeware program called Treesize:-
It showed me a file in my Temp directory, a folder with no name.
 The size of the folder is 91.7GB, and my C drive is running out of space because of it.
I suspect malware to have created it, and am at the moment running Windows Malicious Malware Tool, to try and find the source of the problem. I have thus far discovered two infected files. Anyway, Treesize found this nameless hidden folder for me, and shows me all it's contents, including many many files with a size of well over 100 MB.

Comment: welcome to superuser:- software rec's should be made on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/16535/disk-space-usage-utilization-analysis-for-windows/46201#46201  this way the site does not be come a poss spam site. again welcome