# How do I access a folder without name?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, batch, batch-file

This is the example .......

[image]

The problem is that the flash memory have occupied 5GB of 8 gb but when I access the memory does not show me anything.
I used the following command

```
dir /a:hd d:\
```

But nothing shows, only two directories. But you can not access because it has no name.

When I check the directory with this statement

```
C:\Windows\System32>dir /a d:\
```

shows me the following

```
 Volume in drive D is FLASH
 Volume Serial Number is 94A8-15A7

 Directory of d:\

File Not Found
```

But if check with this statement

```
C:\Windows\System32>dir /a d:\
```

shows me the following

```
 Volume in drive D is FLASH
 Volume Serial Number is 94A8-15A7

 Directory of d:\

10/25/2016  09:38 PM    <DIR>                                   //**THIS**
10/26/2016  10:12 AM    <DIR>          System Volume Information
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
               2 Dir(s)   2,211,725,312 bytes free
```

I dealt with this command

```
D:\>dir /x
```

and showed me the following

```
Volume in drive D is FLASH
 Volume Serial Number is 94A8-15A7

 Directory of d:\

File Not Found
```

Also try this command

```
mkdir "\\?\D:\temp\ "
```

of this example 
[Accessing the contents of a Nameless folder](https://superuser.com/questions/583870/accessing-the-contents-of-a-nameless-folder)

I created the folder well and when I check shows me the following

```
 Volume in drive D is FLASH
 Volume Serial Number is 94A8-15A7

 Directory of d:\temp\

10/27/2016  07:56 AM    <DIR>          .
10/27/2016  07:56 AM    <DIR>          ..
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
               2 Dir(s)   2,211,692,544 bytes free
```

Now when I try to make the second command

```
copy "D:\temp\ \*.*" D:\temp
```

OR

```
copy "\\?\D:\temp\ \*.*" D:\temp
```

shows me this

```
D:\temp\ \*.*
The system cannot find the file specified.
        0 file(s) copied.

\\?\D:\temp\ \*.*
The system cannot find the file specified.
        0 file(s) copied.
```

I do not know if I'm doing something wrong....

**What I can do?**
*How do I access a folder without name?*

Comment: What happens if you use the `/x` option like this:  `dir /a:hd /x d:\ ` ?

Comment: `for /F "delims=" %G in ('dir /B /a:hd D:\^|findstr /V "e"') do @dir /S "%~G\"`

Comment: I use  dir /a:hd /x d:\ not  show me anything....

Comment: There is no way that it has "no name". The folder name probably contains some invisible character like the Right-to-Left Override or something like that. Bluntly speaking, the best solution is to *rename* your *nameless* folder.

Comment: try `dir /x` only. If it not a hidden folder, it will not show when using `/a:hd` because you are filtering. As far as accessing whats in there: see for example http://superuser.com/questions/583870/accessing-the-contents-of-a-nameless-folder

Comment: @Yorik Idealt with this example but use the next command `copy "D:\temp\ \*.*" D:\temp` or `copy "\\?\D:\temp\ \*.*" d:\temp` showed me the following :
`D:\temp\ \*.*`
`The system cannot find the file specified.`
      `0 file(s) copied.`

Comment: Use `dir /w` to identify the amount of unknown characters.

Answer (score 1):

> **But you can not access because it has no name**

It very likely has a name. It is just that you are having trouble finding out what the name is.

For example, it is easy to create a directory with a name of " "

[image]

[image]

Comment: The OP hasn't mentioned using Windows 10 Pro in his/her question. I very much doubt that s/he runs Bash on Ubuntu on Windows(WSL) as it is strictly a developer's feature.

Answer (score 1):

After trying all commands and look for similar situations, testing the dir command with its attributes in the help I saw that there was an attribute to list all directories and subdirectories:

```
C:\>dir /?
Displays a list of files and subdirectories in a directory.

DIR [drive:][path][filename] [/A[[:]attributes]] [/B] [/C] [/D] [/L] [/N]
  [/O[[:]sortorder]] [/P] [/Q] [/R] [/S] [/T[[:]timefield]] [/W] [/X] [/4]

  [drive:][path][filename]
              Specifies drive, directory, and/or files to list.

  /A          Displays files with specified attributes.
  attributes   D  Directories                R  Read-only files
               H  Hidden files               A  Files ready for archiving
               S  System files               I  Not content indexed files
               L  Reparse Points             -  Prefix meaning not

/S          Displays files in specified directory and all subdirectories.\\**THIS**
```

I saw the folder and appears in the list of your directories.
After trying giving space to access it press tab to complete me and appeared well:

```
 C:\>dir /a/s d:\
     Volume in drive D is FLASH
     Volume Serial Number is 94A8-15A7

 Directory of d:\

10/25/2016  09:38 PM    <DIR>           
10/26/2016  10:12 AM    <DIR>          System Volume Information
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
 Directory of d:\ \PVR **This (d:\ \)**

01/01/1980  12:04 AM    <DIR>          .
01/01/1980  12:04 AM    <DIR>          ..
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
```

knowing he could autofill your way to use the command tab

```
C:\>attrib  d:\ 
   SH        D:\ 
C:\>attrib -S -H D:\ 

C:\>attrib  D:\ 
             D:\
```

ready and I could see the new folder in the browser and access the information contained therein.
thank you very much everyone for your time.